# Using user defined smtp when sending email through Mailable class with Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel

Title says it all. I am trying to create an app where user can define their own smtp and send emails to their clients using my app. How can i manually change the smtp information that Mailable class would use?

Queueing the messages is important too, so i guess the Mailable class should somhow have smtp information.

One solution that i can think of is to create an EMail model and save all data needed to send email including smtp settings from user to database. Then, i can make a queued job that retrieves this model and just calls send method on Email object. That send method news mailable class, sets smtp config with *Config::set()* and sends it.

Will it work or my thinking is flawed...

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the `\Illuminate\Mail\TransportManager` class, in the `createSmtpDriver()` method, you will find where the SMTP settings are pulled in the from the config. In your config, if you have your driver set to `smtp` Laravel will call this method.

The Laravel `Mailer` class contains a public method to set the the Swift Mailer instance. So you could essentially create your own instance and pass that through before you send your message (I haven't tested this):

```
public function yourMethod(Mailer $mailer)
{
    $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance(
        'YourHost', 'YourPort'
    );
    $transport->setUsername('YourPassword');
    $transport->setPassword('YourPassword');
    $swift = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

    $mailer->setSwiftMailer($swift);

    $mailer->send(...);
}
```

Usually, if you want to introduce some custom functionality into a Laravel class like Mailer, you would be able to define your own driver (In this case your own transport) and use Laravel's API to extend it and add your own method of sending mail.

Again, I have not tested this but you could potentially extend the `TransportManager` class to add your own driver. You could put the following code in say `AppServiceProvider`:

```
$manager = app('swift.transport'); // Will get you an instance of TransportManager
$manager->extend('customsmtp', function() {
    // Your custom code to create your own transport for the mailer. Just like the createSmtpDriver method in TransportManager.
    $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance(
        'YourHost', 'YourPort'
    );
    $transport->setUsername('YourPassword');
    $transport->setPassword('YourPassword');

    return $transport;
});
```